# How to make a function for atan. I want to get result manually for SQLLITE

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

How to make a function for atan. This will be working inside SQLLite Query. I have needed acos but I got formula of acos in this needed atan.

newCos = 2 * atan( sqrt(1-pow(var,2))/(1+var) );

But we need atan function for run this

Comment: You want to use a trigonometric function inside a SQLite query?  If that's the case, you need to look into `sqlite3_create_function`.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Is your question about how to use the standard `atan` math function from a SQLite query or is your question about how to implement an `atan` function in general?

Comment: We want to get distance from lat long for this we need atan. MySQL have these all functions but I have distance inside sqllite. So that's why I need to create this function manually inside sqllite then I will able to fetch record. Otherwise first need to download all record then need to get distance and show.. but its not possible on big volume of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distance function for sqlite.....  in SQL acos working can manage using this .. May Be helpfull

As part of an iPhone SDK project, I have an sqlite database with a table full of geographic locations, each stored as a latitude and longitude value in degrees. I wanted to be able to perform an SQL SELECT on this table and ORDER BY each row’s distance from an arbitrary point. I’ve achieved this by defining a custom sqlite function. This article contains the code for the function, together with instructions on using it.

Here’s the function, together with a convenience macro to convert from degrees to radians. This function is based on an online distance calculator I found which makes use of the spherical law of cosines.

```
#define DEG2RAD(degrees) (degrees * 0.01745327) // degrees * pi over 180

 static void distanceFunc(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv)
 {
  // check that we have four arguments (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
  assert(argc == 4);
   // check that all four arguments are non-null
 if (sqlite3_value_type(argv[0]) == SQLITE_NULL || sqlite3_value_type(argv[1]) == SQLITE_NULL || sqlite3_value_type(argv[2]) == SQLITE_NULL || sqlite3_value_type(argv[3]) == SQLITE_NULL) {
   sqlite3_result_null(context);
  return;
 }
// get the four argument values
double lat1 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[0]);
double lon1 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[1]);
double lat2 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[2]);
double lon2 = sqlite3_value_double(argv[3]);
 // convert lat1 and lat2 into radians now, to avoid doing it twice below
double lat1rad = DEG2RAD(lat1);
double lat2rad = DEG2RAD(lat2);
// apply the spherical law of cosines to our latitudes and longitudes, and set the result appropriately
 // 6378.1 is the approximate radius of the earth in kilometres
 sqlite3_result_double(context, acos(sin(lat1rad) * sin(lat2rad) + cos(lat1rad) *    cos(lat2rad) * cos(DEG2RAD(lon2) - DEG2RAD(lon1))) * 6378.1);

 }
```

This defines an SQL function distance(Latitude1, Longitude1, Latitude2, Longitude2), which returns the distance (in kilometres) between two points.

To use this function, add the code above to your Xcode project, and then add this line immediately after you call sqlite3_open:

```
sqlite3_create_function(sqliteDatabasePtr, "distance", 4, SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, &distanceFunc, NULL, NULL);
```

…where sqliteDatabasePtr is the database pointer returned by your call to sqlite3_open.

Assuming you have a table called Locations, with columns called Latitude and Longitude (both of type double) containing values in degrees, you can then use this function in your SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Locations ORDER BY distance(Latitude, Longitude, 51.503357, -0.1199)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear but it seems that you know how to write your own custom SQLite functions meaning that your actual question is about how to write the various trigonometric functions.

You don't need to write them. Simply use the standard math functions.

```
#import <math.h>

double newCos = cos(someRadianAngle);
```

See the man page for `cos`, `sin`, `tan`, `atan`, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Do 1 thing pass var1 & var2 to function & then use getValue in query. Xcode has in built atan,acos function you just need to pass value in radians.

```
float getValue=[self calculatetan:(float)var1 withSecondValue:(float)var2];


-(float)calculatetan:(float)var1 withSecondValue:(float)var2
{
     newCos = 2 * atan( sqrt(1-pow(var,2))/(1+var) )// or split this 
     return newCos;
}
```

Comment: Why is a function that calculates the cosine named `calculatetan:withSecondValuw:`? Why not simply use the standard `cos` function from `math.h`?

Comment: We want to get distance from lat long for this we need atan. MySQL have these all functions but I have distance inside sqllite. So that's why I need to create this function manually inside sqllite then I will able to fetch record. Otherwise first need to download all record then need to get distance and show.. but its not possible on large amount of data..

Comment: Above answer is totally wrong. I need simple math formula for atan after that I will convert into SQLLite