# How to enable / define trig functions for Session() of a sqlite database?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm very new to programming and currently developing a flask app based on sqlite3 db using sclalchemy.

I have realized that no trigonometric functions are by default available using sqlite.
And I read many many guides and SO questions, which propose:

1. Define the functions myself using C/C++
   [No such acos function exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165073/no-such-acos-function-exists)
   [How to make a function for atan. I want to get result manually for SQLLITE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267624/how-to-make-a-function-for-atan-i-want-to-get-result-manually-for-sqllite)
   [acos function in Sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612538/acos-function-in-sqlite)
2. Load the extensions (created by myself, or from [www.sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org))
   [How to load a SQLite3 extension in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851097/how-to-load-a-sqlite3-extension-in-sqlalchemy)
3. Or alternatively just enable the math functions SQLITE_ENABLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS
   [Logarithm function in sqlite query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551884/logarithm-function-in-sqlite-query)
   and here
   https://www.sqlite.org/lang_mathfunc.html
4. Lastly,
   I found a another one:
   https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function

Basically create_function on connection.
Example from the source:

```
import sqlite3
import md5

def md5sum(t):
    return md5.md5(t).hexdigest()

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.create_function("md5", 1, md5sum)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select md5(?)", ("foo",))
print cur.fetchone()[0]
```

I have absolutely no knowledge of C/C++, therefore the 4th solution seemed the easiest to implement in a Flask app. However, for my queries I use Session() and pass it sqlalchemy commands. Since I am very in need of at least one solution working for using trig functions, **my question is if there is a way to pass the connection to the session? (So i define trig functions for a connection and then session inherits connection?)**

If it doesn't make sense,
I would be very happy to implement other solutions.

For instance the guide from solution [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851097/how-to-load-a-sqlite3-extension-in-sqlalchemy)  suggests this:

```
from sqlalchemy.event import listen

# initialization routine
# app: this Flask application
# db: the database, see the question 
db_collate = 'sk_SK.UTF-8'   # Slovak language for example
def load_extension(dbapi_conn, unused):
    dbapi_conn.enable_load_extension(True)
    dbapi_conn.load_extension('/path/to/libSqliteIcu.so')
    dbapi_conn.enable_load_extension(False)
    dbapi_conn.execute("SELECT icu_load_collation(?, 'ICU_EXT_1')", (db_collate,))
with app.app_context():
    listen(db.engine, 'connect', load_extension)
```

However I do not understand if this is a universal solution,
since i've no idea what does these lines mean:

```
db_collate = 'sk_SK.UTF-8'
dbapi_conn.execute("SELECT icu_load_collation(?, 'ICU_EXT_1')", (db_collate,))
```

In my case I found this file [extension-funtion.c](https://www.sqlite.org/contrib/download/extension-functions.c) which I was hoping to implement in my flask web app. (It has all trig functions written in C; the link to sqlite official website)

In the end I will be happy to do something like this:

```
query = session.query(Parent).filter(cos(Parent.age) < 0.5).all()
```

where `cos` is either defined or preinstalled or enabled but is still doing the cos.

Please bear with me, I'm coding only for a month and lacking the theory, which I am just starting to deep in.

P.S. if there is some essential read that I cannot move on without, pls let me know also!

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

Yes, I am trying to get the distance on a sphere in a Flaks app using sqlalchemy Session()

I tried to implement the solution that @IljaEverilä [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061014/accessing-table-variables-in-flask-sqlalchemy-query-during-search)

That is how now my **init**.py looks like (the db section)

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///app.db', echo=False)
@event.listens_for(db.get_engine(), 'connect')
def create_math_functions_on_connect(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    dbapi_connection.create_function('sin', 1, math.sin)
    dbapi_connection.create_function('cos', 1, math.cos)
    dbapi_connection.create_function('acos', 1, math.acos)
    dbapi_connection.create_function('radians', 1, math.radians)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'
login.init_app(app)
Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
```

However, when I make a new session and query the db, I get the error:

```
>>> from app import Session
>>> session = Session()
>>> x = session.query(Parent).filter(cos(Parent.age) < 0.5).all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cos' is not defined
```

Comment: What is the reason you need to define those in SQLite? Can you please explain a bit more  what you exactly want/are trying to achieve and why you think you need those as a SQLite function.

Comment: You can register them when a new connection is created using SQLA events like you have already tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061014/accessing-table-variables-in-flask-sqlalchemy-query-during-search

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks a lot. Just like everyone else I am trying to figure out the distance on a sphere. The question you have shared partially answers my question. However, what I am really interested is if this function will be automatically defined for sqlalchemy sessions? You made a comment that you have to predefine functions before other stuff with db. I added more info on how my code looks, and would be very thankful if you could have a look

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for bearing with me! I figured out one of the ways to make it work!

My settings stayed the same:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///app.db', echo=False)
@event.listens_for(db.get_engine(), 'connect')
def create_math_functions_on_connect(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    dbapi_connection.create_function('sin', 1, math.sin)
    dbapi_connection.create_function('cos', 1, math.cos)
    dbapi_connection.create_function('acos', 1, math.acos)
    dbapi_connection.create_function('radians', 1, math.radians)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'
login.init_app(app)
Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
```

I did not figure out how to pass defined functions to sqlalchemy, but I used raw sql in the filter clause instead and it worked!

```
from app import Session
from sqlalchemy.sql import text


session  = Session()
query = session.query(Parent).filter(text('cos(Parent.age)>0.5')).all()
```

Appreciate if you can share the way to pass it (defined functions) to sqlalchemy, but otherwise it works!

Comment: Just use `sqlalchemy.func`, for example `func.cos(Parent.age) > 0.5` in Python.